# How to parse this data

Tags: linux, bash, text-editing

I have a file filled with data like this:

```
15-06-18 22:00 2968
```

Each entry is separated by a new line. I want to extract the last number (2968). How can I do this? (I am on Linux with `bash`).

Sorry if I don't have the right tags/am posting in the wrong place. I'm not sure where to place this question.

Comment: Is the number you want to extract always immediately after the second blank space?

Comment: If I understand you right, yes. There's never more spaces.

Comment: I guess what I was asking was for you to reliably define the character patterns; exactly where that number will always be found.  Is it always a four-digit number?  Does it always start at the 16th character position?  Does it always follow `nn-nn-nn nn:nn `?  Can there ever be any exceptions?

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Cyrus Oh. Right. Haha, I forgot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the content is in file named 'file', the following should do.

```
cut -d ' ' -f 3 file
```

cut is Unix command. From the man page:

- cut - remove sections from each line of files
- `-d` says the delimiter to use for cutting.
- `-f` which fields to select.
- `file` is the source file.

result goes to standard output.

Comment: `cut` is `unix` command. From the man page ... `cut - remove sections from 
 each line of files`. `-d` says the delimiter to use for cutting. `-f` picks the field(s) (or columns) to cut.

Answer (score 2):

Print last column:

```
awk '{print $NF}' file
```

Output:

```
2968
```

The variable `NF` is set to the total number of fields in the input record. $NF always contains the contents of the last column. Even shorter:

```
awk '$0=$NF' file
```

Comment: The variable `NF` is set to the total **number of fields** in the input record. `$NF` always contains the **contents** of the last column. Even shorter: `awk '$0=$NF' file`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution that removes the first 15 characters.

```
sed 's/^..............//' tmp.txt
```

Thanks, @fixer1234!

Comment: Glad you solved it.  BTW, by my character count, it looks like you want to delete only 15 characters; the 16th is part of what you want to keep.

Comment: Right, sorry. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the data you need using `awk`, `cut` or `sed` or even some combination of grep with regex.

If the data in every line of file you are having, follows the exact pattern you have presented here :

```
15-06-18 22:00 2968
```

Then, you can extract the last number by this :

```
awk '{ print $3 }' file_path
```

And to save the data you may redirect it to another file :

```
awk '{ print $3 }' file_path > new_file
```

#### How it works :

Basically, [awk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html) is a very powerful tool used for textual data manipulation. In your case :

```
15-06-18 22:00 2968
```

Above line can be treated as 3 strings separated by a `space` in between and awk **by-default** treats a space as a separator (given by **`-F`**).

To try out some fun with awk, Try this with your data and you will understand much better.

```
awk -F: '{ print $2 }' your_file
awk -F- '{ print $3 }' your_file
```

Feel free to add in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Or in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat "$1" | while read day hour value ; do
    echo $value
done
```